# Wordpress Sticky post sticking on main blog page, but not in category page (Timber Twig template)

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have all posts showing on a page with:

```
$newsArgs   =   array(
  'post_type'       => 'post',
  'posts_per_page'  => 6,
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'paged'           => $paged,
    'orderby'       => array(
    'date'          => 'DESC'
));
```

Sticky posts stay at the top of the list correctly.

Then in another template I have a page of posts within a category:

```
$categoryArgs   =   array(
  'post_type'       => 'post',
  'category_name'   => 'category',
  'posts_per_page'  => 6,
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'paged'           => $paged,
    'orderby'       => array(
    'date'          => 'DESC'
));
```

The only difference is the addition of the 'category' but here on the front end the same Sticky posts do *not* stick at the top of the list - do I need to add something to the 'orderby'?